# Using SDF database file for multiple users

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-ce

Can I use an SDF file as a database for a small website where multiple users can access it in the same time? Or is SDF just for a single user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem at all! The `.SDF` is a [SQL Server Compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact) database file.

> Like Microsoft SQL Server, SQL CE supports transactions, referential
>   integrity constraints, locking as well as multiple connections to the
>   database store.
>
> SQL CE runtime mediates concurrent multi-user access to the .sdf file.

You can have multiple users accessing your application at the same time and making use of the same database file.

As SQL CE is a limited version of the full SQL Server, you have some limitations. Take a look at the [Support section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact#Support).